# Recuperar solo la hora, sin la fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta en la cual sí me da el resultado correcto, solo que quisiera recuperar la hora y quitar la fecha.

```
SELECT   
CONVERT(datetime,ARA.vchHrsProductivasFinal)-
CONVERT(datetime,ARA.vchHrsProductivasInicial) AS HORAS
FROM AGRRegistroActividad ARA
where intAGRRegistroActividadKey = 1055

RESULT

HORAS

1900-01-01 06:30:00.000
```

Comment: @Brandon debes ser más específico, ¿SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...? o como bien dice *Yussef* ¿C#, VB, ...?

Comment: Esque para poder hacer la pregunta me pide minimo 3 etiquetas y pues pongo lo relacionado con programacion pero lo que necesito esta con Sql Server, espero puedan ayudarme Saludos.

Comment: Por cierto, ¡NO ES NECESARIO QUE GRITES! Lee [ask]. No agregues etiquetas que no corresponden a la pregunta.

Comment: NO NOS GRITES QUE SIN GRITOS TAMBIÉN ENTENDEMOS!

Comment: No se porque se ofenden la verdad solo son letras mayusculas yo no tengo intencion de gritar solo es una pregunta para que me apoyen que mala onda que sean de esa manera

Comment: @Brandon Porque hay que perder tiempo en reeditar la pregunta, si no queda fea

Comment: Yoseff muchas gracias Hermano ya pude resolverlo y no te ofendas tu yo solo vengo a pedir apoyo Animo Gracias vee hasta eliminaron tu respuesta malo malo

Comment: @Brandon No pasa nada, cero problema por mi lado. Suerte en tu proyecto!!

Comment: Por la buena siempre, parce. Siempre es con buen ánimo pa que la gente te responda más rápido! :)

Comment: En internet, escribir en mayusculas es el equivalente a gritar. Es más. Yo lo leo y mi voz mental grita. Además, desde mi punto de vista, no es una linda forma de "llamar la atención". Perdón si los demás usuarios no hayan reaccionado de la mejor manera (aunque para mi no reaccionaron mal), pero la intención es ayudar a que tu pregunta sea mejor y, por lo tanto, recibas más apoyo.

Comment: Lo mas seguro esque tengamos algo de cultura diferente yo por mi lado no me ofenderia si viera una publicacion con letras mausculas es mas hasta seria mas comprencible para leerlo mejor ya eh creado preguntas anteriormente y creeme que es la primera ves que reaacionan asi no los culpo si se ofenden quiza sea por la cultura que an tenido oh un estandard de regla que no conlleva tomarlo de buena manera cuando ven una publicacion en mayusculas que al fin y alcabo si te das cuenta solo es una publicacion todo el mundo viene aqui esperando ayuda no queriendo insultar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con Convert(varchar, El_datetime, 8) transformas a  hh:mm:ss

```
SELECT   
   CONVERT (varchar, CONVERT(datetime,ARA.vchHrsProductivasFinal)-
   CONVERT(datetime,ARA.vchHrsProductivasInicial),8) AS HORAS
   FROM AGRRegistroActividad ARA
   where intAGRRegistroActividadKey = 1055
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé por qué no te han sugerido usar el tipo de dato `time`. Supongo que si quieres tomar solo la parte del tiempo, no tendrás más de un día o lo ignorarás. En ese caso, puedes usar este tipo para mostrarlo y tener la precisión de fracciones de segundo que desees.

En este ejemplo, también muestro como obtener la diferencia usando funciones de tiempo.

```
SELECT  CAST( DATEADD( MS, DATEDIFF( MS, 
                                     ARA.vchHrsProductivasInicial, 
                                     ARA.vchHrsProductivasFinal), '00:00') AS time(0)) AS HORAS
FROM AGRRegistroActividad ARA
WHERE intAGRRegistroActividadKey = 1055;
```

Ahora que si requieres algo que pueda mostrar las horas aunque sean más de 24 y siga con el mismo formato, puedes usar algo similar a esto.

```
SELECT  STUFF( CONVERT( VARCHAR(20), x.Diferencia,114), 1, 2, DATEDIFF( hh, 0, x.Diferencia))
FROM AGRRegistroActividad ARA
CROSS APPLY( SELECT CONVERT( datetime, ARA.vchHrsProductivasFinal) - CONVERT( DATETIME, ARA.vchHrsProductivasInicial) AS Diferencia)x
WHERE intAGRRegistroActividadKey = 1055;
```

En este caso, como necesito usar la diferencia 2 veces, moví el cálculo a un `APPLY` para poder reutilizar el valor en la fórmula. Así le doy formato de hora a la diferencia y reemplazo las horas con las horas totales (que podrían ser más de 23) usando la función `STUFF`.

Comment: Perfecto lo emplee y me funciono muy bien, gracias por la informacion este tipo de consultas las estare utilizando muy seguido Encerio muchas gracias hermano

Answer (score 0):

Dándole formato al resultado de la operación obtienes eso

```
SELECT   

FORMAT(
    CONVERT(datetime,ARA.vchHrsProductivasFinal)-
CONVERT(datetime,ARA.vchHrsProductivasInicial), 
    N'hh:mm tt'
) AS HORAS


FROM AGRRegistroActividad ARA
where intAGRRegistroActividadKey = 1055
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias Alfabravo otra forma de poder hacerlo (Y)

Comment: La función FORMAT es muy lenta y puede generar problemas de rendimiento en tus consultas.

Comment: Buen dato, @LuisCazares Gracias!